# Keycloak as authentication service for Traefik has delay on logout

Tags: oauth-2.0, keycloak, traefik

I have setup keycloak as authentication service and used it to protect some service using this guide:

https://github.com/ibuetler/docker-keycloak-traefik-workshop

the whole procedure seems to work correctly but when I call the logout route in keycloak OpenID configuration the session in keycloak sessions get deleted immediately but the traefik still route request to protected service for 30 second or so. After that I got redirected to login page to re-login. I think some sort of caching is happening in the traefik.

I expect that after calling the logout route which remove session in keycloak traefik immediately stop routing request to protected service but if I refresh the page with Ctrl+F5 it load the service for 30 second or so and after that It redirect me to login page. how can I fix it to do it without delay?

Answer (score 0):

I  found the problem.
I thought it was Traefik issue but it was Keycloak gatekeeper. It was my mistake in calling the logout URL. I called the Keycloak discovery logout URL but I should have called the gatekeeper logout URL. it was stated clearly in gatekeeper documentation.  "/oauth/logout?redirect=url" route immediately logout user and close the session.